# generate bison output into different folders

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I currently using bison and flex in my project which has the following structure:

```
Project
|
|--include/
|--src/
```

all the headers are going into the `include` directory, and all the source files are going into the `src` directory.
I have my grammars and the flexer grammar in the include directory, and I would like to have the generated header files also in the `include` directory, but the generated source files in the `src` directory.
I there an option or something for bison to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using bison or bisonc++? Please only use tags which apply to the actual tools you are using; otherwise, it is impossible to provide tool-specific answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an excerpt of the output of `bison --help` with relevant command-line options:

```
$ bison --help
Output:
      --defines[=FILE]       also produce a header file
  -d                         likewise but cannot specify FILE (for POSIX Yacc)
  -b, --file-prefix=PREFIX   specify a PREFIX for output files
  -o, --output=FILE          leave output to FILE
```

And for flex:

```
$ flex --help
Files:
  -o, --outfile=FILE      specify output filename
```